# jQuery each() function not working after if/else statement has been completed for both if and else outputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jQuery & javascript to switch the classes for images based on whether the viewport width is less than or greater than twice the width of the image. 
I am using $(window).resize to detect when the widow is resized and then the each() function to iterate through all images of a certain class.
An if statement checks whether the width of the viewport is less than twice the width of the image and if so removes one class and adds another. The else statement does the reverse.

One page load it works fine for as many widow width changes as I do, until both the if and the else have been executed, then they stop working. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Here's my code:

```
    function updateViewportDimensions() {
      var w = window,
        d = document,
        e = d.documentElement,
        g = d.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
        x = w.innerWidth || e.clientWidth || g.clientWidth,
        y = w.innerHeight || e.clientHeight || g.clientHeight;
      return { width: x, height: y };
    };

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {

        var viewport = updateViewportDimensions();

        var viewport_width = viewport['width'];    

        console.log('Viewport width = ' + viewport_width);

        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {      

          $('.alignright').each(function(i, obj){

            // get the width of each image
            var image_width = $(this).width();

            // if the viewport width is less than twice the image width then switch the classes
            if(viewport_width < (image_width * 2)) {
              $(this).removeClass('alignright');
              $(this).addClass('aligncenter');
              console.log('Viewport is less than twice image width');
            } else {
              console.log('Viewport is more than twice image width');
              $(this).addClass('alignright');
              $(this).removeClass('aligncenter');
            };
          });
        });
      });
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "stops working?" Is there an error? Do either of the `console.log` statements appear?

Comment: I mean... your .each only runs over elements that have class A. if you remove class A, there are no longer any elements with class A and therefore it won't iterate over any elements. The logic here seems quite flawed.

Comment: Kevin B - you're completely right - I've been a total idiot...sorry!

Answer (score -1):

If I am reading this correctly, `(this).removeClass('alignright');` is changing your dom. Because of this all the link to the class `alignright` is now new but your jquery is still looking for the instances that have been removed.

Update `$('.alignright').each(function(i, obj){` to be one level higher than what is being altered.

if the code is

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="alignright">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

use `$('#outer-wrapper .alignright').each(function(i, obj){`

Comment: Would that not still have the same problem?

Comment: If it is removing all elements like you mentioned yes. But I am assuming that some were `aligncenter` so they were made `alignright`

Comment: Right, but, this would still result in the ones without alignright never being selectable... and thus never able to regain alignright. It's no different from the code presented in the question functionally.

Comment: True, it looks like there is some logic issues with them being able to be aligned right again. Once that is resolved it looks like it is still going to have the issue I mentioned. That is if they ever expect their window to grow and shrink rather than just one or the other.

Comment: Thanks for the input everyone, feeling like a total moron right now...gonna go back to the start with this one, after I've screwed my very loose head back on!